# Создание модели с полем many-to-many и коэфициентами

Tags: django

Представим, что мы хотим создать базу данных рецептов блюд. Для этого мы создаем в models класс (например class DishModel) и задаем соотношение many-to-many с классом ингридиентов (class IngredientsModel). Но вот тут встает вопрос... Таким образом мы определим только список ингредиентов, но не кол-во, которое нужно добавлять в конечное блюдо.

Вопрос, как правильнее всего было определить поле class DishModel, чтобы хранить связку ингредиент + кол-во?

PS
Читал про MultiValueField, но оно для форм. Есть ли аналог для моделей?

PSS
Задать соответствующее поле в class IngredientsModel, логически не правильно, потому как кол-во ингредиента это именно информация про блюдо, а не ингредиент. Ингредиенты могут использоваться во многих блюдах.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой вариант предложили. И он вроде работает, хотя я пока не до конца разобрался в механике.
Если возникнут альтернативные идеи, или желание объяснить детали работы указанного кода, прошу в себе не держать.

You can define these in a through= model [Django-doc]:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Dish(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
     ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(
          Ingredient, through='DishIngredient', related_name='dishes'
      )

     def __str__(self):
         return self.name


class DishIngredient(models.Model):
    dish = models.ForeignKey(Dish, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=('dish', 'ingredient'), 
                name='ingredient_once_per_dish'
            )
        ]
```

we can then for a dish for example get the DishIngredients and thus print the ingredients with their quantity:

```
dish = # some_dish

for ingredient in dish.dishingredient_set.select_related('ingredient'):
     print(f'{ingredient.quantity} {ingredient.ingredient}')
```